# Pig is not loading csv

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I'm trying to load a pipe delimited file ('|') in pig using the following command: 
    `A = load 'test.csv' using PigStorage('|');`

But I keep getting this error: 
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. java.net.URISyntaxException cannot be cast to java.lang.Error

I've looked all over, but I can't find any reason this would happen. The test file I have above is a simple file that just contains `1|2|3` for testing.

Comment: You might need to escape your separator char `A = load 'test.csv' using PigStorage('\|');`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Pig in MAPREDUCE as the ExecType mode, then the following command should work

```
A = LOAD '/user/pig/input/pipetest.csv' USING PigStorage('|');
DUMP A;
```

Here is the output on your screen

```
(1,2,3)
```

Note that I have included the full path in HDFS for my csv file in the LOAD command